# Proving a function is one-to one.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function. For an element $a\in A$ let $[a]$ denote the set of elements $a'$ of $A$ such that $a\sim a'$. The set $[a]$ is called the equivalence class of $a$ with respect to $\sim$. Let $X=A/\sim$ be the set of all equivalence classes of A under the equivalence relation $\sim$. Prove that the relation $\bar{f} : X \rightarrow B$ defined by $\bar{f}([a])=f(a)$ is a one-to-one (and well-defined) function.

I'm not quite sure how to prove what its asking.

Comment: Without more information about the equivalence I'd say it's a difficult task

Answer (score 2):

You need to prove that:

- $\boxed{\text{$\overline f$ is well-defined}}:$ Given any $[a_1], [a_2] \in X$ such that $[a_1] = [a_2]$, does it follow that $\overline f([a_1]) = \overline f([a_2])$?
- $\boxed{\text{$\overline f$ is one-to-one}}:$ Given any $[a_1], [a_2] \in X$ such that $\overline f([a_1]) = \overline f([a_2])$, does it follow that $[a_1] = [a_2]$?